# find: -exec not terminated with ';'\\ when trying to delete some old files

Tags: linux, unix, hp-ux

i am using the following syntax on an HPUX machine, and have no luck removing older files, getting the following error: find: -exec not terminated with ';'\

```
find /path/ -type f -mtime +90 -name "*.tgz" -exec rm {} \ ;\
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You have a space between \ and ;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is an empty space between `\` and `;`